# Spark KafkaUtils CreateRDD apply filter on key

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I have a huge Kafka topic that contains several key,value messages. I want just to process data with a given key in an RDD, without having to download the whole topic.
Data is also interleaved, so I cannot even rely on the offset in the topic
Any suggestion on how to perform this?

Comment: If your topic is partitioned and you know how the keys are mapped to partitions, you may get away with scanning one specific partition.

Comment: Kafka Spark Streaming is deprecated in favor of Structured Streaming, by the way

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. Need to filter them (all).